# Cumulocity Cloud Fieldbus modbus device (sometimes) does not recognize modbus measurements

Tags: iot, cumulocity

I am using a NETCOMM NTC-6200 modem to connect devices via the modbus TCP protocol.  Using the Cloud Fieldbus application I can register the devices on the modbus registers I want and add the device to cumulocity.
However, once I have done this the measurements only show up sometimes.

To give a concrete example, I am connecting a meter measuring voltage, current and power.  When adding the device the current measurements are recognized and shown.  Upon deleting the device and redoing the entire process, all three measurements are shown.  Repeating a third time results in no measurements being recognized. This can be repeated seemingly at random.

In these cases of "non-recognition" the "measurements" icon in the device menu does not appear and in custom dashboards the device is shown but no data-points are available for the device.

Is there a possibility that the measurement recognition needs some sort of trigger to add the measurement to the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Measurements" icon shows up as soon as there is a measurement stored for the particular device. If it's not shown, there has been no measurement sent by the device yet. There's no configuration required.

Issues with connecting Modbus devices can be "troubleshot" by increasing the log level on the router and requesting a log. You can click on "Shell" and send the command "set service.cumulocity.log.level=8", then click on "Log", select "sragent" from the drop-down box and request a log.

Since this is less a developer-related question, feel free to contact support@cumulocity.com with more details (e.g., open the device management page in the browser and send the URL of that page, so we know the tenant and the device).

Cheers,
André

Comment: Increasing the log level helped!  It seems as though this was a Network Issue and nothing to do with cumulocity.